# Error accessing field [xxx] by reflection for persistent property with IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 4 classes associated with each other as you see below in Spring Boot project.

When i save a **thread** object through ThreadRepository, there is no problem. Automaticly  `List<Tweet> listOfTweets` All `Tweet` objects in the list are saved in the database. When I want to **get all tweets in Tweet table**, I see an error like that in the browser. (part of the output) I mean, There is no problem when you want to save them to database but if you want get them, there is a problem.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet.tweet_id to java.lang.Long
>
> Error accessing field [private java.lang.String com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet.tweet_id] by reflection for persistent property [com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet#tweet_id] : 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet.tweet_id] by reflection for persistent property [com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet#tweet_id] : 1

`tweet_id` already have String type. But I don't know why it want to change to Long type.

Database process doing through Tweet/Thread/Media/LinkRepository interface: (i.e)

```
@Repository
public interface TweetRepository extends JpaRepository<Tweet,Long> {


}
```

TweetServiceImp:

```
@Service
public class TweetServiceImp implements TweetService  {
    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TweetServiceImp.class);

    private final TweetRepository tweetRepository;


    public TweetServiceImp(TweetRepository tweetRepository) {
        this.tweetRepository = tweetRepository;
    }



    @Override
    public List<Tweet> findAllTweets() {
        return tweetRepository.findAll();
    }



}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class SerieController {
    private final TweetService tweetService;
    private final ThreadService threadService;


    public SerieController(TweetService tweetService, ThreadService threadService) {
        this.tweetService = tweetService;
        this.threadService = threadService;

    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/series/allTweets")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Tweet> getAllTweets(){
        return tweetService.findAllTweets();

    }
}
```

Thread Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_thread")
@Getter @Setter @ToString
public class Thread implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true,name = "thread_id")
    private String threadId;
    @Transient
    private Tweet mainTweet;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "thread",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Tweet> listOfTweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
```

Tweet Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_tweet")
@Getter @Setter @ToString
public class Tweet implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false,name = "tweet_id")
    private String tweet_id;
    @Column(name = "parent_tweet_id")
    private String parentTweetID;
    @Column(name = "avatar")
    private String avatar;
    @Column(name = "owner_id")
    private long owner_id;
    @Column(name = "owner_name")
    private String owner_name;
    @Column(name = "owner_nick")
    private String owner_nick;
    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;
    @Column(name = "sent_time")
    private String sent_time;
    @Column(name = "sent_date")
    private String sent_date;
    @Column(name = "retweet_count")
    private String retweet_count;
    @Column(name = "like_count")
    private String like_count;
    @Transient
    private String quotedTweetHtml;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "thread_id",referencedColumnName = "thread_id")
    private Thread thread = new Thread();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tweet",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Media> mediaURLs = new ArrayList<Media>();

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "tweet",cascade = CascadeType.ALL  )
    private Link link;
```

Link Entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @ToString
public class Link implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "attachment_type")
    private String attachmentType;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;
    @Column(name = "url")
    private String url;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "video_url")
    private String videoUrl;
    @Column(name = "video_secure_url")
    private String videoSecureUrl;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tweet_id",referencedColumnName = "tweet_id")
    private Tweet tweet;
```

Media Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_media")
@Getter @Setter @ToString
public class Media implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "media_id")
    private String mediaID;
    @Column(name = "media_type")
    private String mediaType;
    @Column(name = "media_url")
    private String mediaUrl;
    @Column(name = "media_url_https")
    private String mediaUrlHttps;
    @Column(name = "media_video_url")
    private String mediaVideoUrl;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tweet_id",referencedColumnName = "tweet_id")
    private Tweet tweet;
```

Full output:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Error accessing field [private java.lang.String com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet.tweet_id] by reflection for persistent property [com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet#tweet_id] : 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet.tweet_id] by reflection for persistent property [com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet#tweet_id] : 1
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet.tweet_id] by reflection for persistent property [com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet#tweet_id] : 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet.tweet_id] by reflection for persistent property [com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet#tweet_id] : 1
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:351)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.findAll(Unknown Source)
>       at com.savetweet.tweet.Service.Imp.TweetServiceImp.findAllTweets(TweetServiceImp.java:68)
>       at com.savetweet.tweet.rest.SerieController.getAllTweets(SerieController.java:40)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet.tweet_id] by reflection for persistent property [com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet#tweet_id] : 1
>       at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:75)
>       at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:59)
>       at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValue(ComponentType.java:412)
>       at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:239)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.generateHashCode(EntityUniqueKey.java:67)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.(EntityUniqueKey.java:48)
>       at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:733)
>       at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:467)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:172)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:129)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1151)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1010)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508)
>       at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
>       at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
>       at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
>       at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74)
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:73)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>       at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
>       ... 65 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.savetweet.tweet.domain.Tweet.tweet_id to java.lang.Long
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:418)
>       at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71)
>       ... 110 more

Hibernate Output (with findAllTweets()):

```
Hibernate:
        select
        tweet0_.id as id1_3_,
        tweet0_.avatar as avatar2_3_,
        tweet0_.content as content3_3_,
        tweet0_.like_count as like_cou4_3_,
        tweet0_.owner_id as owner_id5_3_,
        tweet0_.owner_name as owner_na6_3_,
        tweet0_.owner_nick as owner_ni7_3_,
        tweet0_.parent_tweet_id as parent_t8_3_,
        tweet0_.retweet_count as retweet_9_3_,
        tweet0_.sent_date as sent_da10_3_,
        tweet0_.sent_time as sent_ti11_3_,
        tweet0_.thread_id as thread_13_3_,
        tweet0_.tweet_id as tweet_i12_3_
        from
        tbl_tweet tweet0_
        Hibernate:
        select
        thread0_.id as id1_2_0_,
        thread0_.thread_id as thread_i2_2_0_
        from
        tbl_thread thread0_
        where
        thread0_.thread_id=?
```

Comment: What DB are you using and what is the type of tweet_id in your db ?

Comment: @Asoub  I'm using MySQL and when I look to MySQL workbench, tweet_id It seems as String. All table automatically created by Annotations as you know. I don't interfere to db side.

Comment: Maybe this is the answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58106714/1971062